# NULLIF does not support set arguments error even though not a set

Tags: postgresql

the `array_to_string` is returning `text` (916-555-1212), however postgresql is treating it as set-operation even with explicit ::text casting.

```
select nullif(
  array_to_string( 
    regexp_matches('9165551212', '(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})')::text[]
    ,'-')::text
  , '');
ERROR:  NULLIF does not support set arguments
```

yet I can use char_length which expects text and it works

```
select char_length(
  array_to_string( 
    regexp_matches('9165551212', '(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})')::text[]
  ,'-')::text
)
 char_length 
-------------
      12
```

yet wrap even that in a nullif and same error

```
select nullif(
  char_length(
    array_to_string( 
      regexp_matches('9165551212', '(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})')::text[]
    ,'-')::text
  )
  ,12)
ERROR:  NULLIF does not support set arguments
```

Comment: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) "*The function can return no rows, one row, or multiple rows*" - and because `regexp_matches` is marked as a function that potentially _can_ return multiple rows, you get this error (even though in your case it wouldn't return multiple rows)

Comment: [also in manual ;)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) "It is possible to force regexp_matches() to always return one row by using a sub-select; this is particularly useful in a SELECT target list when you want all rows returned, even non-matching ones"

Comment: You can force it to _return_ exactly one row, but that doesn't change the fact that it is marked as possibly being _able_ to return more then one (in contrast to e.g. `lower()` which will **always** return a single value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and it seems to be related to the `regexp_matches` function:

```
select nullif(          (regexp_matches( '123', '(2)' )        )[1]      , '' )
;  -- ERROR: NULLIF does not support set arguments
select nullif(          (regexp_matches( '123', '(2)' )::text[])[1]::text, '' )
;  -- ERROR: NULLIF does not support set arguments
select nullif( ( select (regexp_matches( '123', '(2)' )        )[1]     ), '' )
;  -- ok: gives "2"
```

so just wrapping the result in a sub-select seems to solve it here as well :-/

Answer (score 0):

Weird... It works if you do

```
select 
  nullif(
   (
     select array_to_string( 
       regexp_matches(
         '9165551212',
         '(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})'
       )::text[]
       , '-' )
   )
   , '')
```